# Changing Horses Mid-Stream: A New Career in Technology

Tags: professional-education, career, certification

So, after a few years in the professional world of sales, I have finally stumbled onto something that I actually enjoy doing and being around: the wonderful world of IT.  Perhaps I am crazy?  Anyways, after a little thinking and reading, I have decided upon a course into the field of Cyber Security.  I am still doing alot of research, but here is my main concern.

I have 2 bachelors degrees, neither in a science related field.  I do have have 2 years selling computers and various other forms of IT equipment, which is where I have picked up most of my knowledge (either from the Sales certs I have been required to get or from hanging around the Service and Engineering departments and asking questions.)  I have enrolled at the local junior college to start getting a base foundation of knowledge and prepare for some of the entry level certs such as the A+ and Network+..though this has caused some level of consternation amongst friends and colleagues I have shared my plans with.  They seem to think that going back to any type of school is a waste of time and money.  They counsel me that I should just study for the certs on my own and then acquire them that way.

Another consideration is experience.  Sales experience is in no way going to prepare me for the wonderful world of IT that awaits me.  But, at the same time, I have bills to pay.  It seems to be a proverbial rock and a hard place.

So my questions are: 1) school or certs?  I ask because I do want to fully understand what I am doing, but at the same time I do not want to waste time and money only to sabotage myself by become "overeducated" or "overqualified".  2) How would I go about getting the necessary experience in the field?  It has been suggesting that volunteering my time and services would be an excellent way of doing this while maintaining my current level of income.

All advise would be appreciated

Comment: Heads up - this question will almost certainly get closed as it's 'primarily opinion based'. Certs are useful, some more than others, experience is arguably more useful and there's a certain circular dependency between the two. Self study shows discipline and attitude and if you achieve the cert then you end up in the same place. You do need experience though, certs alone do not prepare you for the job. Maybe consider an entry level security position in the specialism of your choice.

Comment: Certifications  you may want to consider (some of these require experience, I wouldn't say any are beginner) CEH, OSCP, CREST, CHECK

Comment: Certs certify your *knowledge*. Focus on the efficient method of getting the knowledge. If you learn best by self-study, do that. Courses also help you in building a network and gaining a wider perspective on the topic and field.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't really a good forum for getting individual career advice.  I'd recommend looking through the r/cscareerquestions, r/itcareerquestions, and r/asknetsec subreddits.